# Glassfish3 cant start cause bootstrap jar not found

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-3

i installed the glassfish3 tools for eclipse juno and i installed
glassfish3 on my computer under C:\glassfish3.

I created a new server with glassfish3 tools for eclipse and everything
was setup correctly.

When i now want to start the galssfish server i get the error:

```
bootstrap jar not found
```

nothing else. No more details and no log output.

how can i get my glassfish running?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same problem, check if folder where glassfish is the same configurated in eclipse.
**Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments**

Answer (score 2):

double click on the server. it will open the server Overview.
Under general information you will find two link. runtime envionment and open launch configuration.
click on runtime environment, you will see some error mark there.
eclipse is not updatind the path when you create a new server or change the server domain path.
I provided the correct path there. however I am using glassfish 4.
it fixed error for me - bootstrap jar not found.